# Find first row where value is less than threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame where I try to find the first `ID` for when the `left` is less than the values of

```
list = [0,50,100,150,200,250,500,1000]
```

```
             ID  ST  ...          csum           left
0             0  AK  ...  4.293174e+05  760964.996900
1             1  AK  ...  4.722491e+06  760535.679500
2             2  AK  ...  8.586347e+06  760149.293900
3             3  AK  ...  2.683233e+07  758324.695200
4             4  AK  ...  2.962290e+07  758045.638900
..          ... ...  ...           ...            ...
111         111  AK  ...  7.609006e+09     107.329336
112         112  AK  ...  7.609221e+09      85.863469
113         113  AK  ...  7.609435e+09      64.397602
114         114  AK  ...  7.609650e+09      42.931735
115         115  AK  ...  7.610079e+09       0.000000
```

So I would end up with a list or dataframe looking like

```
threshold      ID
        0      115
       50      114
      100      112
      150      100
      200      100
      250       99
      500       78
     1000       77
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: have a look at [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "**just** exceeds"?. In terms of "left" value or position?

Comment: @mozway sorry. I mean I want to extract the first `ID` of the value larger than the list values.
E.g. for the `left` that is 107.32, I want to get the `ID` for the row before.

Comment: @QuangHoang I need to incorporate the term `left` < list[values] which is not possible with `merge_asof`.

Comment: I think it does, play with the `direction` param.

Comment: Why not? Although you didn't follow a strict `<` in your example, 0 shouldn't match anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the ID of the first value greater than the target, use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
lst = [0,50,100,150,200,250,500,1000]

pd.merge_asof(pd.Series(lst, name='threshold', dtype=df['left'].dtype),
              df.sort_values(by='left').rename(columns={'left': 'threshold'})[['threshold', 'ID']],
              # uncomment for strictly superior
              #allow_exact_matches=False,
)
```

Output:

```
   threshold   ID
0        0.0  115
1       50.0  114
2      100.0  112
3      150.0  111 # due to truncated input
4      200.0  111 #
5      250.0  111 #
6      500.0  111 #
7     1000.0  111 #
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [0,50,100,150,200,250,500,1000]
df11=pd.DataFrame(dict(threshold=list))
df11.assign(id=df11.threshold.map(lambda x:df1.query("left<=@x").iloc[0,0]))
```

out

```
   threshold   ID
0        0.0  115
1       50.0  114
2      100.0  112
3      150.0  111 # due to truncated input
4      200.0  111 #
5      250.0  111 #
6      500.0  111 #
7     1000.0  111 #
```